# What could cause my password to become incorrect?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

My MacBook Pro (Late 2013) running Yosemite (10.10.3) seems to have decided my password is incorrect and fails to log me in. I have managed to change the password via my Apple ID but I'm concerned that the system has somehow been compromised.

- The previous password was typed correctly, numerous times, on the built-in keyboard and a wireless keyboard.
- That password had successfully allowed me to login several hours prior to the problem.
- To the best of my knowledge, no software was installed and no system settings were modified during the session prior to the problem.

Is there any known issue that could have caused this? Is there a way to see some kind of system change log so I can audit previous activity and make sure nothing malicious has happened?

Comment: My guess would be an accidental change in the keyboard layout (can be done via Command plus space if you have more than one active) or accidental leaving caps lock key in on position.

Comment: Nice idea but almost certainly not the case. I only have one keyboard layout and it does not appear to have changed. The caps lock key was obviously one of the first things I checked.